# Why is the latest Android Build ID starting with the letter A?

Tags: android-versions, builds

In the following list of *"Source code tags and builds"* the first entry has the build id `AP1A.240305.019.A1`.
https://source.android.com/docs/setup/reference/build-numbers#source-code-tags-and-builds

I find this strange, as based on the *"Build ID definitions"*, the first letter is supposed to be the *"letter of the codename of the platform release"*, which seemed to follow an ascending alphabetical order so far.
https://source.android.com/docs/setup/reference/build-numbers#build-ids-defined

Out of pure curiosity, does anyone have any idea as to what caused the sudden jump to `A`?